# Android UI testing - ActivityScenarioRule is significantly slower then ActivityScenario

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, instrumented-test, androidx-test

I'm getting into Android UI testing, and I learnt two ways to start up activities: `ActivityScenario` in each test, and `ActivityScenarioRule` once, annotated with `@Rule`.

At first I used `ActivityScenario`, with success. Each test took **around 2-4** second to complete:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        ActivityScenario<MyActivity> scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MyActivity.class);
        //do testing...
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        ActivityScenario<MyActivity> scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MyActivity.class);
        //do testing...
    }

    //more tests...
}
```

Then I decided to switch to an `ActivityScenarioRule`, since I have a decent amount of tests written, and with a rule, I don't need to create an `ActivityScenario` to each test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyActivityTest {

   @Rule //launch this activity before each test
   public ActivityScenarioRule<MyActivity> rule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(MyActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        //do testing...
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        //do testing...
    }

    //more tests...
}
```

If I run the tests with this rule, each test takes around **40-50 seconds** and most of it is spent on this screen:

[image]

Tests are run on an emulator. I don't know what this screen is and why it takes up so much time when using `ActivityScenarioRule`. When using `ActivityScenario` in each test, this screen does not show up and tests complete fast. Please help, what am I missing?